# Opening external file can produce error OR creation in read mode

Tags: python, file, external, ioerror

Last night I wrote a program that pulls all the commented lines out of a file and outputs them to a new file. This is something we often have to do in my programming class, and picking through the files copying and pasting gets old really quick.

I have a check for both my input file and output file to see if they exist. If the input file does exist, all good continue on -- if not, ask for another file name. If the output file does exist, ask the user if the want to overwrite -- if it doesn't exist, all good carry on.

The problem I'm having is that one check correctly throws an IOError when file = open(fileName, 'r') does not find the file, the other check creates a blank file instead of giving the IOError.

This is especially baffling since the two bits of code are nearly identical. Same process, just different filename variables...

The code is below. The second part is the one that creates a blank file. First gives error as expected.

```
# Try to open the input file
inFileOpen = False
while not inFileOpen and userTrying:
    # If it opens, all good
    try:
        inFile = open(inFileName, 'r')
        inFileOpen = True
    # If it doesn't open, ask user to try a different file
    except IOError:
        ...

# Try to open the output file
toFileOpen = False
while not toFileOpen and userTrying:
    # If the file opens in r mode, that means it exists already, so ask user if they
    # want to overwrite the existing file, if not ask for a new file name
    try:
        # ********************
        # For some reason, 'r' mode is creating a file... no clue...
        # ********************
        toFile = open(toFileName)
        toFile.close() # I have tried removing this just guessing at solutions. Didn't work.

        # ... Ask if user wants to overwrite

    # If the file can't be opened, all good, that means it doesn't exist yet
    except IOError:
        toFileOpen = False
        toFile = open(toFileName, 'w')
```

Comment: Just checking: have you made sure that the `except` block is not executed (e.g. by putting diagnostic `print` messages there)? Because if it is executed, then it's the second open that creates an empty file, and that would be expected.

Comment: shouldn't your last `toFileOpen` be set to `True`?

Comment: Lev Levitsky - Yes. Forgot to mention that. If I type in a filename that absolutely does not exist, it never hits the except block.

Comment: Oh my goodness. Jeff I was getting ready to type out why I had set that to false and then realized some modifications I did to the program make my reasoning irrelevant. That solved my issue...

Comment: Lev Levitsky - Come to think of it, I must have only put a print statement in the try block under the file open part.

Comment: I think that `os.path.isfile()` is probably a better way to see if a file exists.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Python 3.3, `open` has an "x" mode which is the same as "w" except that it will raise a `FileExistsException` if the file is already there. This is better than a separate check because it is atomic and immune race condition between the test for the file existing and opening it for writing. While this probably isn't an issue for your current script, but might matter in a more security critical program.

In older versions of Python (2.x and 3.0-3.2) it's a little more tricky. One option would be to open the file for appending ("a" mode) and then inspect the current stream position (using `tell`) to see if it already contained something. If it did, but the user wants to replace the old contents, you can call `truncate()` and then `seek(0)` to erase the current data and get back to the start of the file. This could still potentially overwrite a zero-length file without notice, but I suspect that's not a big problem. Another approach is to pass the `os.O_EXCL|os.O_CREAT` flags explicitly to `os.open`, then pass the file descriptor returned to `os.fdopen` to get a regular Python file object. This is essentially what the "x" mode does behind the scenes.

**Edit**: Here's a nifty context-manager solution to creating an output file given suitable `get_filename` and `confirm_overwrite` functions that do the actual interaction with the user. This code is for Python 3.3, but the `open` calls and perhaps the `except` statement can be modified to make it work for earlier versions.

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def create_output_file():
    while True:
        out_filename = get_filename()

        try:
            with open(out_filename, "x") as f:
                yield f
            break

        except FileExistsException:
            if confirm_overwrite(out_filename):
                with open(out_filename, "w") as f:
                    yield f
                break
```

Use it with a `with` statement:

```
with create_output_file() as f:
    f.write("whatever")
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the os.path.exists(filename) would be a good way to check files:

Eg.

```
 while not os.path.exists(infile):
     infile = askfilename()
 with open(infile) as f:
     for line in f:
         ...
```

You can do similar for the outfile